# 2d Array from JSON with MINIJson

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I am a bit noob on JSON and really also c#
Anyway I need to load some JSON and setup a gamegrid in unity3d based on a 2d array with the contents from JSON file.

I use MINIJson from Darktable which I succesfully can fetch simple data with, but my brain freezes when i try to unwrap the json below :-(

I hope someone would offer me a short script to do it with MINIJson.

I hope to be able to make my game grid from this Json:

{
"layout" : [ [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ],

}

I can get the data from my JSON file like this

```
TextAsset t = (TextAsset) Resources.Load("levels/Level_0", typeof(TextAsset));
    string jsonString = t.ToString();
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(jsonString) as Dictionary<string,object>;
    Debug.Log("dict['layout'][0]: " + ((List<Object>) dict["layout"])[0]);
```

But how would I go about to get this json from the dictionary to my

```
int layout[9,9]
```

I hope someone will be able to help.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[,] layout = new int[9,9];

var dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)Json.Deserialize(jsonString); 
var list = (List<object>)dict["layout"];

for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
    var items = (List<object>)list[row];
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
        layout[row, col] = Convert.ToInt32(items[col]);
    }
}
```